# Quorum Ethereum Truffle) Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle, quorum

I am actually learning smart contract programming on ethereum and I work with truffle. Right now I am making this tutorial here: https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

Where you learn how to create a dapp with quorum. But now I have a problem.

I did everything exactly as described, but when I do:

```
truffle migrate
```

I get this error here:

```
$ truffle migrate
    ⚠️  Important ⚠️
    If you're using an HDWalletProvider, it must be Web3 1.0 enabled or your migration will hang.


    Starting migrations...
    ======================
    > Network name:    'development'
    > Network id:      10
    > Block gas limit: 3758096384


    1_initial_migration.js
    ======================

       Deploying 'Migrations'
       ----------------------
       > transaction hash:    0x0a55cd010bb30247c3ae303e54be8dd13177b520af5967728cf77e07ca9efe76
    - Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
       > Blocks: 0            Seconds: 0
       > contract address:    0x1932c48b2bF8102Ba33B4A6B545C32236e342f34
       > account:             0xed9d02e382b34818e88B88a309c7fe71E65f419d
       > balance:             1000000000
       > gas used:            245462
       > gas price:           0 gwei
       > value sent:          0 ETH
       > total cost:          0 ETH


    - Saving migration to chain.
    Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
        at assert (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\number-to-bn\~\bn.js\lib\bn.js:6:1)
        at BN.toNumber (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\number-to-bn\~\bn.js\lib\bn.js:506:1)
        at Object.hexToNumber (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-utils\src\utils.js:234:1)
        at Method.outputBlockFormatter [as outputFormatter] (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth\~\web3-core-helpers\src\formatters.js:239:1)
        at Method.formatOutput (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth\~\web3-core-method\src\index.js:163:1)
        at sendTxCallback (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-eth\~\web3-core-method\src\index.js:473:1)
        at C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:147:1
        at C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:145:1
        at C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-provider\wrapper.js:112:1
        at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:96:1)
        at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:1)
        at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:1)
        at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:1)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dany.vandermeij\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:47)
        at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    Truffle v5.0.1 (core: 5.0.1)
    Node v8.11.4
```

Now I don't know why...

Does anyone have the same problem and can help me out here?

This is my Smart Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint public storedData;

  constructor(uint initVal) public {
    storedData = initVal;
  }

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() view public returns (uint retVal) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

And my truffle-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22000, // was 8545
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodefour:  {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22003,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodeseven:  {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22006,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.4.25",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  }
}
```

And the migration file:

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  // Pass 42 to the contract as the first constructor parameter
  deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, 2, { privateFor: ["ROAZBWtSacxXQrOe3FGAqJDyJjFePR5ce4TSIzmJ0Bc="] })
};
```

Comment: Did you try to send the `privateFor` argument as a `BN`?

Comment: Hello @ferit , sorry, can you explain what you mean? I actually just did exactly as the tutorial.

Comment: https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/

Comment: @ferit I installed this bn.js file now. But I still get this error

Comment: I don't mean installing it. I mean sending the argument as a `BN` object. Your hex looks like too big number for Javascript Number so BN might work.

Comment: I actually removed the privateFor argument. So right now its just: deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, 2); but I still get the error

Comment: Try the arg `2` as `BN` as well. Also maybe it's because the gasPrice is 0. Just guessing blindly.

Comment: @ferit , I actually removed the number parameter. so now I only have: `deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage);` but it still doesn't work

Comment: I tried to change the gasPrice, but then it gives me an error that the price has to be set to 0

Comment: @ferit would you like to do teamviewer to help me? I really need help to get this to run. Would be very grateful for your hel

Comment: I could but I'm too busy at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @ferit okay, when would you have time? I need to start on the project on 4th of february...

Comment: The problem is in the timestamp of the getBlockByNumber / getBlockByHash calls. RAFT keeps track of timestamps in nanoseconds, where it would be seconds otherwise. Timestamp in nanoseconds are too big to fit in a JS number, causing the error you're seeing.

Comment: @edgraaff thank you for your comment, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Good question, I haven't found a good solution for it yet. Can you try this? https://github.com/edgraaff/quorum-rpc-proxy It's a proxy that converts timestamps along the way. Edit your truffle config to point to this proxy (port 7545).

Comment: Hello @edgraaff , I would be soo happy if this works. So in my truffle-config.js, should I change the networks to point to the config? And what do I have to do in the proxy that it points to the virtual machine where my quorum nodes are?

Comment: @edgraaff , Bro. It worked!! Man you are my hero. Thank you very very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem was that the Block Timestamp was in Nanoseconds.

@edgraaff wrote a Proxy who converts the Timestamp from Nanoseconds to Seconds. 
You can find the code here -> https://github.com/edgraaff/quorum-rpc-proxy

What I had to do is to clone the proxy and change the config.js file to:

```
module.exports = {
  rpcUrl: 'http://localhost:22000',
  port: 7545
};
```

And in the truffle-config.js file i had to change the port. Here's the code:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545, // was 8545
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodefour:  {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22003,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodeseven:  {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 22006,
      network_id: "*", // Match any network id
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },

  // Configure your compilers
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.4.25",    // Fetch exact version from solc-bin (default: truffle's version)
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks to @edgraaff

Comment: @edgraaff , one problem remains, now I actually have 7 nodes. Do I have to configure the proxy for each node?

Comment: I've updated the project to allow multiple proxies, feel free to extend the config to proxy to each of your nodes. This (closed) issue describes the same problem: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/415 . Web3js doesn't allow an easy way to alter this behavior (altering the getBlock result formatter). So a proxy in between to modify the timestamp .. not the prettiest solution but at least gets you going before february 4th :)

Answer (score 4):

The proxy is not enough, because web3.js can get block in subscribtion via ws

Also in quorum getting block by number is broken, it accept only hex, however web3.js assume hex as blockhash

Here is my solution

```
web3.extend({
  property: 'eth',
  methods: [new web3.extend.Method({
    name: 'getBlockByNumber',
    call: 'eth_getBlockByNumber',
    params: 2,
    inputFormatter: [web3.extend.formatters.inputBlockNumberFormatter, v => !!v],
    outputFormatter: web3.extend.formatters.outputBlockFormatter
  })]
});
web3.utils.hexToNumber = v => {
  if (!v) return v;
  try {
    return numberToBN(v).toNumber();
  } catch (e) {
    return numberToBN(v).toString();
  }
};
```

Just take care that timestamp is string now

Here is related issue in web3.js repo https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1215

Answer (score 3):

For now (May 2020), basically you have two options to work it around:

1. Add `type: "quorum"` in `truffle-config.js` or `networks.js` like:

```js
    myLocalQuorum: {
      protocol: 'http',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 22000,
      gas: 5000000,
      gasPrice: 0,
      networkId: '*',
      type: "quorum"
    },
```

2. If you are using `@truffle/hd-wallet-provider`, there's no simple workaround for it, but you can switch your consensus to `istanbul` instead of `raft`, see the [oz community](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/deploy-smart-contracts-on-quorum-running-raft-consensus-mechanism/1784/3) for more details.

> When running the default consensus Istanbul BFT, I can deploy and interact with a contract using Truffle and OpenZeppelin SDK.
>
> When I switch to RAFT I wasn’t able to deploy a contract using truffle migrate nor oz create. I didn’t see anything different I needed to do config wise in the Truffle documentation for RAFT. by @abcoathup

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix: Just add `type: "quorum"` in your **truffle-config** for the network which is supposed to run on quorum.

Comment: Does it work really? I think it is required anyway: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/distributed-ledger-support/working-with-quorum `type: "quorum"` does not solve issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any proxy if you downgrade your truffle version to 4.1.15. If you do that everything will work fine. Just don't downgrade to 4.1.14 because truffle init it's broken in that package!.

Answer (score 0):

@QuorumPrivateBlockChain hey mate.

So this is my truffle-config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*",
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodefour:  {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7546,
      network_id: "*",
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    },
    nodeseven:  {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7547,
      network_id: "*",
      gasPrice: 0,
      gas: 4500000
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.4.25",   
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my config.js file from the proxy:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    rpcUrl: 'http://localhost:22000',
    port: 7545
  },
  {
    rpcUrl: 'http://localhost:22003',
    port: 7546
  },
  {
    rpcUrl: 'http://localhost:22006',
    port: 7547
  },
];
```

So what you do, you send the requests from your truffle to your proxy and the proxy then converts the timestamp and sends the request further to the node.

The proxy is a program by itself, you don't have to copy the config.js file form the proxy code. Look into the github how you can start the proxy.