# How to fix " Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits" in my script?

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle, quorum

I'm trying to create storage contract with Quorum 7nodes, but I have this problem: 
Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Javascript:

```
 await contract.methods.set(5).send({ from: accounts[0]});
```

contract in solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
  uint storedData;

  function set(uint x) public {
    storedData = x;
  }

  function get() public view returns (uint) {
    return storedData;
  }
}
```

versions:

```
Truffle v5.0.14 (core: 5.0.14)
Solidity v0.5.0 (solc-js)
Node v10.15.1
Web3js "^1.0.0-beta.52"
```

truffle config:

```
  nodefour: {
        host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
        port: 22003,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
        network_id: 10,       // Any network (default: none)
        gasPrice: 0,
        gas: 4500000,
        type: "quorum" },
```

Comment: If you need to store integers with more than 53 bits you should look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: I dont need to store more than 53 bits, my integer is just "5" --> contract.methods.set(5)

Comment: you linked my Question

Comment: By searching for "Quorum 7 node 53 bits" I found someone else that had the same problem:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128954/quorum-ethereum-truffle-error-number-can-only-safely-store-up-to-53-bits/54256655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because Raft stores the block timestamp in nanoseconds (instead of seconds), and Truffle is unable to handle this.
A simple solution is to use Istanbul or Clique consensus instead.

Alternatively, there is a thread here that describes how to set up a proxy to work around this: [Quorum Ethereum Truffle) Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128954/quorum-ethereum-truffle-error-number-can-only-safely-store-up-to-53-bits/54256655)

Answer (score 0):

**Ultimate Solution**

Simple install web3 latest version which is version 4

`npm install web3@v4.0.1-alpha.1`

That solved my problem